# blogdown::new_site() fails change directory setwd(site.dir)

Tags: r, blogdown

I want to create a site using blogdown.

I've followed instructions in [blogdown's book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/), on [blogdown repos](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/), in posts by [alison hill](https://alison.rbind.io/post/up-and-running-with-blogdown/) and [Ed Borasky](https://www.znmeb.mobi/2017/05/12/getting-started-with-blogdown/). In each case i've got the same error:

```
> blogdown::new_site()
trying URL 'https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium-theme/archive/master.zip'
downloaded 116 KB

Serving the directory /home/ediman/otest at http://127.0.0.1:4321
To stop the server, run servr::daemon_stop("142992016") or restart your R session
Error in setwd(site.dir) : cannot change working directory
```

The R session informations was:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
[4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.14          rstudioapi_0.7.0-9000 plotly_4.7.1          servr_0.8            
[5] knitr_1.17            bindr_0.1             magrittr_1.5          munsell_0.4.3        
[9] viridisLite_0.2.0     colorspace_1.3-2      R6_2.2.2              rlang_0.1.4.9000     
[13] httr_1.3.1            plyr_1.8.4            dplyr_0.7.4           tools_3.4.3          
[17] grid_3.4.3            data.table_1.10.4-3   gtable_0.2.0          htmltools_0.3.6      
[21] yaml_2.1.15           lazyeval_0.2.1        assertthat_0.2.0      digest_0.6.12        
[25] tibble_1.3.4          bookdown_0.5          bindrcpp_0.2          tidyr_0.7.2          
[29] purrr_0.2.4           ggplot2_2.2.1         htmlwidgets_0.9       glue_1.2.0           
[33] blogdown_0.3          compiler_3.4.3        scales_0.5.0          jsonlite_1.5         
[37] httpuv_1.3.5          pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

Can i get helped since i don't figure out what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling `blogdown::new_site()` in an *empty* directory?

Comment: Yes @meenapram. The empty directory is named otest in the example above

Comment: Cannot reproduce, admittedly on an older version (win10, R-3.3.1, `blogdown-0.1.4`).

Comment: Please @meenaparam, @r2evans can you let me know the variable `blogdown.publishDir ` in your .Rprofile point out to what directory?

Comment: What is your `blogdown.publishDir` option?

Comment: @AnicetEbou I'm using the default `publishDir` i.e. `public/` under the project's root directory. Did you try a temporary publish directory as per this: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/more-global-options.html

Comment: The ```blogdown.publishDir``` option is set to ```../public``` in the .Rprofile file of Rstudio.